# How long did Marvin the robot live?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

In The Hitchhicker's Guide trilogy, Marvin ends up living for a very long time.  How long does he live before he finally dies?

Comment: And he spent all that time doing stuff like that:

http://bcn.boulder.co.us/~neal/humor/marvin-the-server-404.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In So Long and Thanks For All The Fish, before he dies, Marvin claims to be "thirty-seven times older than the Universe itself".

Comment: It's all that time travel...